# Impersonation in self-hosted WCF?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, impersonation

I'm currently developing a WCF service self hosted in a Windows service with the [Self-Hosted SL Svc](http://www.bricewilson.net/blog/2010/11/09/self-hosted-wcf-service-for-silverlight/) template.
The template works as it should be and I'm able to make calls from my Silverlight application, but when I tried to modify the project to use Impersonation:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
public string GetData(int value)
{
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

It throws me an exception during `host.Open();`:

> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled   Message=The contract
>   operation 'GetData' requires Windows
>   identity for automatic impersonation.
>   A Windows identity that represents the
>   caller is not provided by binding
>   ('CustomBinding','http://tempuri.org/')
>   for contract
>   ('IService1','http://tempuri.org/'.

This is my configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="SLServiceLibrary.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SLServiceLibrary.ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="Service1" binding="customBinding" contract="SLServiceLibrary.IService1" bindingConfiguration="binaryHttpBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SLServiceLibrary.IClientAccessPolicy" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEnablingBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SLServiceLibrary.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpEnablingBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

What do I have to change to make this work? do I need to add some configuration to my Silverlight client too?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a long search, I've come up with two solutions, one I found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

The other one was at the [Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/182374/413262.aspx):

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Negotiate"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Don't know what is the major difference between these two, I've managed to open the service and call it from Silverlight successfully. If someone call elaborate on the difference, I would appreciate it.

Comment: According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789031(VS.100).aspx) Negotiate can be faster as it uses Kerberos protocol if it's available (which is faster), or NTLM authentication if its not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used custom bindings (yet), but this blog entry may give you some help:  http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2007/10/03/wcf-impersonation---specifying-windows-authentication-credentials-on-the-service.aspx